# material ui: find which component create this tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tags

I would like to find which `React.Component` create this tag:

[image]

I use `styled` component:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const Tabs = styled('div')(({theme})=>({
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
}));
```

Comment: Please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `label` property to your component to make it easier to find the element inside DOM-tree:

```
const Tabs = styled('div')(({theme})=>({
  label: 'test,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
}));
```

After that, the class of the element will get a suffix and it'll look like:

```
<div class="css-w35fh1-test">
```

This property comes from [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/labels).